# Subsitiute for Template.my_template.rendered call back for re-rendering after event fire

Tags: javascript, events, meteor

After Meteor 0.8.0 the `rendered` callback is executed only once, when the template is inserted into the DOM. This causes problems for code that depended on the previous functionality of rendered.

I've tried the following solution, which gives me a few `Deps` errors.

Creating a function, and then calling it in the `rendered` callback as well as whenever the event fires.

`var update_post thumbs = function() { stuff... }`

Then I call it in the template events

`Template.my_template.events = { 'click input' : function(event) { update_post_thumbs(); } }`

As well as in the rendered callback

`Template.my_template.rendered = function() { update_post_thumbs(); }`

Whenever the template is rendered I get the following error:

```
[15:36:28.366] "Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: update_post_thumbs@http://localhost:3000/client/js/answer_submit.js?e5c5233b74e520c0941483e44f4b390f682707f8:98
Template.post_action_bar.rendered@http://localhost:3000/client/js/answer_submit.js?e5c5233b74e520c0941483e44f4b390f682707f8:199
UI.Component.notifyParented/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b523ef986d3d39671bcb40319d0df8982acacfe8:424
.flush@http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?7afb832ce6e6c89421fa70dc066201f16f9b9105:331
"
```

And whenever the event is fired, I get this error:

```
[15:37:13.978] "Exception in delivering result of invoking 'update_vote_count_question': update_post_thumbs@http://localhost:3000/client/js/answer_submit.js?e5c5233b74e520c0941483e44f4b390f682707f8:98
Template.post_action_bar.events["click .post-thumbs"]/<@http://localhost:3000/client/js/answer_submit.js?e5c5233b74e520c0941483e44f4b390f682707f8:179
Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?148e9381d225ecad703f4b858769b636ff7a2537:822
._maybeInvokeCallback@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:3505
.dataVisible@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:3534
._runAfterUpdateCallbacks/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:4217
_.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156
._runAfterUpdateCallbacks@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:4216
._livedata_data@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:4206
Connection/onMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:3375
._launchConnection/self.socket.onmessage/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:2705
_.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156
._launchConnection/self.socket.onmessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:2704
SockJS</REventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:150
SockJS</SockJS.prototype._dispatchMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:1135
SockJS</SockJS.prototype._didMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:1193
SockJS</SockJS.websocket/that.ws.onmessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:1340
"
```

The event runs a function on the server, I wait for it's results then I fire the `update_post_thumbs()`

The data is updated properly in the database, so the function fired on the server is functioning fine.

Comment: I created a test app with just the code you posted in your example and it works fine, no errors.  Your error output mentions 'update_vote_count_question' so I suspect you do not have a minimal case here.  It's possible that the error is generated from within the called function, and doesn't have to do with how you have arrange to call the update function.

Comment: See https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback